Platformio-ide-terminal in Atom not installed
I have
Atom    : 1.60.0
Electron: 9.4.4[enter image description here][1]
Chrome  : 83.0.4103.122
Node    : 12.14.1

I try to set up platformio-ide-terminal via cmd and via Settings. I have fail
cmd
C:\Users\natal\.atom\packages>apm install platformio-ide-terminal
Installing platformio-ide-terminal to C:\Users\natal\.atom\packages C:\Users\natal\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\install.js:256
          if (body.releases.latest) {
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
    at C:\Users\natal\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\install.js:256:29
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\natal\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\lib\request.js:57:22)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\natal\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\natal\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\natal\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.60.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)

Settings
Searching for “platformio-ide-terminal” failed.Show output…


Did you search that error message yet? I just did and here's the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190872/how-to-install-script-in-atom-after-sunsetting-of-atom-if-possible
